# Can anyone explain this code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a sequence of sound frequencies for a project I'm working on. I'm not too experienced in JavaScript and came across this code that I'm thinking about implementing in my project; the problem is I'm not sure what it does. It looks like a key value function of some sort. Can someone explain this and if it is possible to add multiple values to the "values" part on the right side of the colon?

```
const freqMap = {
  1: 250,
  2: 329.6,
  3: 398,
  4: 462.2,
  5: 350,
  6: 400,
  7: 290,
  8: 300,
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics

Comment: Where did you come across this code? Can you provide some context, at least a link maybe? Can you ask the author what this is supposed to do?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It really is key value for example
`freqMap['1']` or `freqMap[1]` will return 250 you can assign array to the value like so
`const freqMap = { 1: [250, 300], ... };`

Answer (score 1):

This is called an Object, which is a JavaScript key:value store.

For example, `freqMap[1]` will return `250`. You could assign an array or another object: `1: [250, 500]` or `1: { 1: 250, 2: 500 }`.